# Empty array exist when I do array_push php

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to push array element to array of array,

```
      $datas = array()
      $data = array(
        'module' => 'abc',
      );

      array_push($datas,$data);
```

When I try to print $datas with print_r

```
      print_r($datas);
```

And the result is:
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [module] => 
            [key] => po_reminder
         )   
)
```

It always have element[0] in the beginning, is that normal, can I have no element 0 in it because the original array supposed to be empty.

Comment: Your code works fine (except for the missing ;) : https://3v4l.org/sidq0

Comment: your print_r o/p is not as expected, where did you got `key`

Comment: what is your problem? I am unable to understand.Your code is working fine:-https://eval.in/860450

Comment: Hi Alive, first I have servera array element. I want to add the element array to an array of array. Then I will do looping on the array of array.

Comment: Is having 0 as the first array key normal? Short answer: that is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code for merge two array

```
$merge = array_merge($datas, $data); 
print_r($merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you simply wanna do `array_merge()`.

Your code is right. If you push $array1 to $array2 like `array_push($array2,$array1)` the result will looks like this:

```
$array2 [
    $array1[]
]
```

$arary1 will be placed at $array2[0] as long as its the first element/e.g. pushed to an empty array

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge instead

or you can use array_filter after array_push

```
$datas = array()
$data = array(
  'module' => 'abc',
);

array_push($datas,$data);

$datas = array_filter($datas);
```

Comment: It works, but then the starting array index will be 1

Comment: $datas = array();